# Legend items appearing too small in QGIS print layout

Tags: qgis

The legend entries are displaying very small. You can see in the top left corner of the legend frames. All the symbology is done but can't see them correctly In the legend frame. I have refreshed and lost all my legend entries so don't want to do that again. Any advice?

[image: legend]

Answer (score 1):

In legend item properties, you can change Fonts and Text formatting. maybe it's the thing you want.
[image]

Comment: What is the page size?

Comment: Thank you found it